# Vim Search and Replace to a single backslash

Tags: vim

I am trying to replace all "\\" into "\" in a selection.

I tried using `:'<,'>s/\\\\/\\/g` to do the substitution, but vim would replace "\\" with "\\".

If I use `:'<,'>s/\\\\/\/g` instead, vim replaces "\\" with "/g".

Is there a way to specify the substitute string is literally a single backslash?

Comment: Your first version works fine for me. Could you add an example input to your question?

Comment: Yes, the first version is correct: Matches two backslashes (doubled for escaping), replaces with one (again doubled for escaping).

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your selection by using:

```
\%V pattern \%V
```

Like this:

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\\\\\%V/\/
```

For further information read:

```
:h \%V
```